# Is there a difinitive answer to what causes catastrophic failure in delphi

Tags: mysql, sql-server, delphi

I have read a few/lots of things on this but they don't seem to help much.

I have an App (it's called "TieUp" but that is irrelevant) I run it manually daily to collate data from several locations.

It is using as sources:

A) Data from a remote SOAP source and loaded into an in-memory TClientDataset via an XMLtransform setup.

B) CSV files downloaded daily and loaded into an in-memory TClientDataset

C) A Mysql Database on the same computer as the program (it's a restored backup of the live source)

D) A remote MS-SQL (SQLServer 2008) database

E) A Mysql Database on a remote server

Data is only read from sources A, B, C and D
Data source E is updated with the consolidated data.

There are between 800 to 2000 records daily so the datasets are not vast although the target (E) has grown to around 150,000 and increasing daily.

I can normally run this all happily and everything works as expected if a little slowly because of all the individual remote lookups to the MS-SQL system) but some days it really screws up and the error is always "Catastrophic Failure!".

The failure does not occur during any particular phase or operation that I can see. The steps are:

1) Get the SOAP(A) data first.

2) Tie in with CSV/In Memory data(B).

3) Lookup References data on Sources C and D to collate

4) Write the consolidated data to source E

After reading in the data into the in memory datasets every thing is In TClientDatasets accesses via DatasetProviders linked to TSQLQueries (they all on the same servers currently but I did it that way to keep some flexibility in future where it might goes true three tier). All queries are contained within the SQLQuery components as they are actually quite simple - it's just a matter of tying things together.

I am using completely standard components from Delphi 2009 Enterprise. All updates and database update packs have been applied. Each data source has its own DataModule these are auto created at startup

There is obviously quite a lot of data access going on here but when it crashes (with catastrophic failure) It gets stuck, completely stuck. Windows can't end the task from the normal "TieUp has stopped working" I have to go to the process and kill it.

There is so much going on and as this only happens once a week or so I really don't know where to start looking.

The reasons for asking the question is twofold: 1) is that I am trying to eliminate any manual stuff and fully automate it, but I can't rely on it if if bombs every week or so. 2) if it happens in the update phase to E - I have to manually delete the new records for the day and start again as I do not have (or haven't written yet) a mechanism to restart from a random point and I would still have to query the DB manually to establish that point for certain.

My next step is to install Delphi on another computer and always run it under the debugger until I can catch it, if it does not freeze first. But that introduces yet another different network connection (instead of the local host one).

So: "Is there a definite answer?" or what is the most likely offending component/connection? Where is the favoured place to start looking?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would *start* with compiling madExcept or Eurekalog into my application en have it send the exception with all the nuts and bolts they offer to me. The alternative is to write down the exception adress, run the application under the debugger *with the same settings you compiled it* and use Search -> Goto error to find the offending piece of code.

Comment: It would help if you could show the precise exact error. And please do use the debugger (or even better, madExcept) to work out the source of the error.

Comment: If there were a definitive answer you wouldn't get a 'catastrophic failure' but a specific exception. Catastrophic failure often means inappropriate memory use and/or memory trashing has occurred. Go with madExcept or EurekaLog as already suggested by Lieven and David.

Comment: @Lieven et al Hmm, I had forgotten about mad except - I installed it once upon a time. I'll start there.

Comment: @Serg - Is that a definitive answer or just funny :)

Comment: The most definite answer I aware of is 42.

Comment: I would suggest also: 1) do some plain text file logging about what the program is doing, 2) do your step E in transactions, 3) check for memory leaks